# ReactJs render doesn't update properly on data change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

EDIT: below is the component created in two different ways, and neither are working. Help is still needed.

Solution 1 using createReactClass

```
//Here are imports of my component


var ListPeople = createReactClass({
  people: [],

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.people = [];
    if(nextProps.peopleSuccess.content.length > 0) {
      this.people = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < nextProps.peopleSuccess.content.length; i++) {
        this.people.push(<Person
      checkboxValue={nextProps.peopleSuccess.content[i].checkboxValue}
      email={nextProps.peopleSuccess.content[i].email}
      emailValidation={nextProps.emailValidation}
      handleEmailChange={nextProps.handleEmailChange}
      handleOnBlur={nextProps.handleOnBlur}
      handlePersonSelect={nextProps.handlePersonSelect}
      handlePhoneChange={nextProps.handlePhoneChange}
      handleUsernameChange={nextProps.handleUsernameChange}
      id={i}
      identity={nextProps.peopleSuccess.content[i].identity}
      key={i}
      name={nextProps.peopleSuccess.content[i].name}
      phone={nextProps.peopleSuccess.content[i].phone}
      phoneValidation={nextProps.phoneValidation}
      usernameValidation={nextProps.usernameValidation} />);
  }
 }
},

  render: function() {
  console.log('this.props.peopleSuccess: ', this.props.peopleSuccess);
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.people}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
});


export default ListPeople;
```

Solution 2 having the component as a function

```
import React from 'react';
//import createReactClass from 'create-react-class'
import Person from '../components/Person';

function ListPeoplePeople(props) {
  const { peopleSuccess, emailValidation, handleEmailChange, handleOnBlur, 
          handlePersonSelect, handlePhoneChange, handleUsernameChange, 
          phoneValidation, usernameValidation } = props;
  let people = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < peopleSuccess.content.length; i++) {
    people.push(<Person
      checkboxValue={peopleSuccess.content[i].checkboxValue}
      email={peopleSuccess.content[i].email}
      emailValidation={emailValidation}
      handleEmailChange={handleEmailChange}
      handleOnBlur={handleOnBlur}
      handlePersonSelect={handlePersonSelect}
      handlePhoneChange={handlePhoneChange}
      handleUsernameChange={handleUsernameChange}
      id={i}
      identity={peopleSuccess.content[i].identity}
      key={i}
      name={peopleSuccess.content[i].name}
      phone={peopleSuccess.content[i].phone}
      phoneValidation={phoneValidation}
      usernameValidation={usernameValidation} />);
  }
  return (
      <tbody>
        {people}
      </tbody>
    );
}

export default ListPeoplePeople;
```

When I put a console.log() in the render it is logging the correct data, and now the data is coming from a parent component that connects into a Redux store, and originally it is fetched from REST API.

react/redux package versions:

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-redux": "^5.0.4",
"react-router": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
"redux": "^3.6.0"
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the data from? Is it in this component or a container component?

Comment: The data is coming from REST API, and it is passed to People component with props: dataIUse: state.dataIUseComingFromReduxStore.

Comment: OK, but in which component are you fetching the data from? is it this component (People), or is it a parent/container People component?

Comment: Above code is not my original component of course, but all the things related to this problem is here. I think that react doesn't re-render properly when the data changes. Why could that be?

Comment: The fetch is done in parent component when it mounts. And the data is correct in the console.log(this.people) that is in the render.

Comment: Then in that case, you want use `connect` in the parent component. Not in people component.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the connect function used everytime I use something from my redux store? I am dispatching actions from this component, and I have other stuff too I need connect for.

Comment: Yes you do, but you use connect on container components, not the functional stateless ones. People component functional stateless.

Comment: Okey, I am new to react/redux and my coding patterns etc might be little weird or inproper. But that shouldn't affect this issue though.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I completely forgot this question, I have gotten it to work now! I can't remember what was the key thing that got it working, but I anyway changed the whole code to follow something similar that of your answer. I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this seems like an improper use of `react-redux` connect method. You should call connect on a `container` component and not a functional stateless component, like what People component seems to be. So the correct usage would be something like the following:

```js
// Container
function Container(props) {
  // get 
  return <People 
    dataIUse={props.dataIUse}
    handleCheckBoxChange={switchChecboxes}
  />
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    dataIUse: state.dataIUseComingFromReduxStore
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
switchChecboxes: (data, index) => dispatch(changeChecboxValue(data, index))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);

// People
function People(props) {
  const { dataIUse } = props;
  let people = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < dataIUse.length; i++) {
    people.push(<Person
      checkboxValue={dataIUse[i].checkboxValue}
      email={dataIUse[i].email}
      id={i}
      identity={dataIUse[i].identity}
      key={i}
      name={dataIUse[i].name}
      onChange={props.handleCheckBoxChange}
      phone={dataIUse[i].phone}/>);
  }
  return (
    <tbody>
      {people}
    </tbody>
  ); 
}
```

Instead of using React.createClass, i've used function. They should work, but make sure you import react on top of your file.

Comment: I will try this suggestion, but in my case the origin of data is not the issue, it is the rendering of it. And I do not see how this fixes it.

Comment: I marked this as accepted answer, but realized that it is not actually working, so still having the issue. I'll add a comment of two different solutions I tried that didn't work.